Unable to provide permissions to USB device on android 14
I am new to Android studio, I am trying to read a rotary data connected to my machine using USB.
I could able to read data from /dev/ttyACM0 using cat command.
I have created a basic application with buttons and text view box as counter, now i am trying to get the USB data from rotary knob and show it in text view box as a counter or characters.
I have written below code after following some online blogs and android studio guide.
https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/usb/host
when i try to read the data using below code, i could see requestPermission() getting called but when i give permission BroadcastReciever() is not getting called & nothing happens.
MainActivity.kt
package com.example.middisplaz

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsControllerCompat

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    private val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.example.middisplaz.USB_PERMISSION"
    private var usbManager: UsbManager? = null
    private var device: UsbDevice? = null
    private var connection: UsbDeviceConnection? = null

    private val usbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == action) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    val device = intent.getParcelableExtra(
                        UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE,
                        UsbDevice::class.java
                    )
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                            UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED,
                            false
                        )
                    ) {
                        device?.apply {
                            setupDevice(this)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("USB", "Permission denied for device $device")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupDevice(device: UsbDevice) {
        val usbInterface = device.getInterface(0)
        val endpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(0)

        connection = usbManager?.openDevice(device)
        connection?.claimInterface(usbInterface, true)

        Thread {
            val buffer = ByteArray(64)
            while (true) {
                val bytesRead = connection?.bulkTransfer(/* endpoint = */ endpoint,
                    /* buffer = */ buffer, /* length = */
                    buffer.size, /* timeout = */ 1000
                )

                if (bytesRead != null && bytesRead > 0) {
                    val receiveData = String(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    Log.d("USB", "Received: $receiveData")
                }
            }
        }.start()
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var counter = 0
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.counterValue)

        val plusButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.plusBtn)
        plusButton.setOnClickListener {
            counter++
            text.text = counter.toString()
        }

        val minusButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.minusBtn)
        minusButton.setOnClickListener {
            counter--
            text.text = counter.toString()
        }

        val windowInsetsController =
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
        // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars.
        windowInsetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

        usbManager = getSystemService(USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager

        val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)
            addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
        }

        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
        val deviceList = usbManager!!.deviceList
        for (deviceEntry in deviceList.values) {
            Log.d("USB", "Device name : ${deviceEntry.deviceName}")
            if (deviceEntry.deviceClass == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_COMM) {
                device = deviceEntry
                requestPermission(device!!)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MutableImplicitPendingIntent")
    private fun requestPermission(device: UsbDevice) {
        val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        usbManager!!.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver)
        connection?.close()
    }
}


AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MidDisplaz"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Any inputs on why the BroadcastReciever or onReceiver() is not getting called, would be appreciated.
Thanks
Tried the above giving code.
